# How to prove this inequality using contradiction

Tags: logic

I need to show that for $x>0,\: x+\dfrac{1}{x}\ge 2$. I have tried a few steps but couldn't proceed. Can anyone help me with the steps involved ?

Comment: Why prove using contradiction? Directly by AM-GM $\;x+\frac{1}{x} \ge 2 \sqrt{x\frac{1}{x}}=2\,$.

Comment: The assigment says to prove in contradiction method sir.. Thnk you

Comment: @dxiv, thanks for the correction. I missed that part. The original question was $x>0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x > 0$. Assume to the contrary that $x +\frac{1}{x} < 2$. Multiply both sides by $x$, which results in $x^{2}+1 < 2x$ which implies that $x^{2}-2x+1 = (x-1)^{2} < 0$. For $x \in \mathbb{R}$, this is clearly a contradiction, so $x +\frac{1}{x} \geq 2$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\exists \: x>0\ni\: x+\dfrac{1}{x}<2\implies x^2+1<2x\implies x^2-2x+1<0\implies (x-1)^2<0$, which cannot hold. Hence the result.

Answer (score 1):

If $x>0$
and $x+1/x <2$
then
$0>x-2+1/x
=(\sqrt{x}-1/\sqrt{x})^2
\ge 0$,
a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Write

$$x+\frac1x<2$$

and transform it until you obtain an obvious absurdity.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be weird:

$x+\frac 1x < 2$ then

$(x+\frac 1x)^2=x^2+2+\frac 1 {x^2}<4$

$x^2+\frac 1 {x^2}<2$

Thus by induction $x^{2^k}+\frac 1 {x^{2k}}<2$

So $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} x^{2^k}\le 2$ and $\lim \frac 1 {x^{2^k}}\le 2$.

For $b>0$ $\lim b^n = \infty $ if $b>1$ and $=0$ if $b <1$ and $=1$ if $b=1$.

So both $x $ and $\frac 1x$ are less than or equal to $1$.  This is only possible if $x=\frac 1x=1$.

So $x+\frac 1x =2$.  A contradiction.

...or...

$x < x+1/x <2$ so $1/x > 1/2$

Likewise $1/x <x+1/x < 2 $ so $x>1/2$

And $x < 2-1/x <3/2$ and $1/x < 2-x <3/2$

So $1/2 < x,1/x <3/2$

So $x = 1+k $ for some $-1/2 <k < 1/2$

$x+\frac 1x= 1+k +\frac 1 {1+k}$

$=1+k+\frac {1+k}{1+k}-\frac {k}{1+k} $

$=2+k-\frac k {1+k}<2$ so $k <\frac k {1+k}$.  So $1+k <1$ and $k<0$.

So $x <1$

But I could just as easily argued $1/x = 1+j$ and I'd have reached the conclusion $1/x < 1$

Which is a contradiction.